# Linq to Xml - Empty Element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am parsing an xml doc with Linq, but i am running into a scenario where I am not sure how to handle the processing.  Everything I have found / tried doesn't seem to work.  As you can see below (very simple scenario) where the OrderAmount is empty.  This is a decimal field.  When I try to handle this in LINQ it keeps bombing.  I have tried using deimcal?, using the null check, etc nothing seems to be working (Most likely user error).  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

How do you handle when an element is a non string (like a decimal) and is empty  ?

Xml:

```
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <OrderNumber>12345</OrderNumber>
    <OrderAmount/>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

LINQ:

```
List<Order> myOrders = from orders in xdoc.Descendants("Order")
                       select new Order{
                       OrderNumber = (int)orders.Element("OrderNumber"),
                       OrderAmount = (decimal?)orders.Element("OrderAmount"),


}.ToList<Order>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cast of `XElement` to `decimal?` returns `null` only when the element is actually `null`.

I think the most readable solution is something like this:

```
elem.IsEmpty ? null : (decimal?)elem
```

You might want to put this into an extension method, if you use it often. Or just use `let` in your LINQ query to not repeat the code that selects the element.

```
from orders in xdoc.Descendants("Order")
let amountElem = orders.Element("OrderAmount")
select new Order
{
    OrderNumber = (int)orders.Element("OrderNumber"),
    OrderAmount = amountElem.IsEmpty ? null : (decimal?)amountElem
}
```

Another option, if you can change the XML, is simply omitting the element to represent `null`. It should work well with the code you already have.

**EDIT:** The extension method would look something like this:

```
static class XElementExtensions
{
    public static decimal? ToNullableDecimal(this XElement elem)
    {
        return elem.IsEmpty ? null : (decimal?)elem;
    }
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
OrderAmount = orders.Element("OrderAmount").ToNullableDecimal()
```

Comment: Hi @svick...could you show me an example of applying an extension method here? I appreciate the info!

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
OrderAmount = String.IsNullOrEmpty(orders.Element("OrderAmount").Value) ? 
                  default(decimal?) : Decimal.Parse(orders.Element("OrderAmount").Value),
```

Per svick's comment, this might be safer

```
OrderAmount = String.IsNullOrEmpty(orders.Element("OrderAmount").Value) ? 
                  default(decimal?) : (decimal)orders.Element("OrderAmount"),
```

Comment: Using `decimal.Parse()` like this is dangerous, because it uses culture-specific formatting to do the parsing. It may work well on your computer, but not on mine. I believe using the casts from `XElement` is safe in this regard.

Comment: @svick - fair enough - it's easy to forget about other cultures - I'm not a good enough developer to write stuff that's used worldwide :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the element's value rather than the element itself.

Edit:  If you're really set on keeping the cast, here is a passing unit test that you can work with to get in a format perhaps more pleasing to the eye:

```
    private XDocument BuildDocument()
    {
        var myAmount = new XElement("OrderNumber", 12345);
        var myNumber = new XElement("OrderAmount");
        var myOrder = new XElement("Order", myAmount, myNumber);
        var myOrders = new XElement("Orders", myOrder);
        return new XDocument(myOrders);
    }

    private class Order
    {
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal? OrderAmount { get; set; }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var myDoc = BuildDocument();
        List<Order> myOrders = (from orders in myDoc.Descendants("Order")
                               select new Order
                               {
                                   OrderNumber = (int)orders.Element("OrderNumber"),
                                   OrderAmount = GetAmount(orders.Element("OrderAmount"))
                               }).ToList<Order>();
    }

    private static decimal? GetAmount(XElement e)
    {
        if (e == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))
        {
            return 0.0M;
        }
        return (decimal?)e;
    }
```

(You'll still have to add code for dealing with the case where the value of OrderAmount is something like "Asdf")

Comment: That's what the casts are for. They access the element's value and convert it to the specified type, if possible. But it uses different rules for nullity than the XML in question.

Comment: Well, the cast is invoking System.Number.ParseDecimal(string), which appears not to be equipped to handle nulls.  You're going to have to get the value as a string and do the casting from there, to decimal, supplying a default for failed parse (i.e. contains non-numeric characters, is empty is null, etc)

Answer (score 0):

How have you declared OrderAmount in your Order class? Try declaring

```
public decimal? OrderAmount { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's not the problem here. If it were, it would cause a compile-time error, not data-dependent run-time error.